# Convert YYYYMMDD to Excel dd/mm/yy

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ibm-midrange

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852387/convert-to-text-format-in-excel) Gert Grenander makes a suggestion to format the date field to 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'.

How would I convert from 'YYYYMMDD' to 'dd/mm/yy' in my SQL call using the same method?

Answer (score 2):

```
select date2, 
       digits(date2), 
       (substr(digits(date2),7,2) concat '/' concat 
        substr(digits(date2),5,2) concat '/' concat 
        substr(digits(date2),3,2) 
       ) as mmddyy
  from datesample
```

gives:

```
  Signed                       CHAR       
 data type  DIGITS ( DATE2 )  MMDDYY  
----------  ----------------  --------
20130711    20130711          11/07/13
```

You'll need to convert the decimal value (DATE2) to string via DIGITS, then use SUBSTR to extract the pieces you need, then use CONCAT (or `||`) to reassemble them including the delimiter you want.  If your 'date' column is character, you can leave out the conversion to character.

```
select date4, 
       (substr(date4,7,2) concat '/' concat 
        substr(date4,5,2) concat '/' concat 
        substr(date4,3,2) 
       ) as mmddyy
  from datesample
```

gives:

```
  CHAR     CHAR        
data type  MMDDYY 
---------  --------
20130711   11/07/13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` function in SQL for Converting to desired format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @your_date, 103)
```

[More Here](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: Yeah, great link for those using SQL Server. Unfortunately, the question is tagged `ibm-midrange` which means they are on an IBM iSeries or Power System (the system Watson runs on) and the database, DB2 for i, is embedded into the OS, IBM i. Nonstandard TSQL syntax won't work on standards compliant DB2 for i.